# Device token format for PHP APNS

Tags: php, laravel, apple-push-notifications

I've got this APNS laravel package setup no problem, but I'm not hitting a brick wall with our device tokens.

https://github.com/ZhukV/AppleApnPush

Our tokens are stored in mysql and look much like this (i changed a few chars)

```
'4739a92133dd5311d623e97cbe2d141e1b216c6e'
```

And we keep getting back

```
'Device token must be a 64 charsets, "40".'
```

Is there some special way i should be passing my device token to these methods?

Comment: after your edit your token looks like a device-id. That's not the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call this in your AppDelegate to get the token:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
```

and

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
// Prepare the Device Token for Registration (remove spaces and < >)
NSString* devToken = [[[[deviceToken description]
                        stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<"withString:@""]
                       stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""]
                      stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];
NSLog(@"devToken=%@",devToken);
}
```

A token looks like this:

bbb4231be5df46d6e9c1e4c3418ad56456c671eb7101818d8cc9ac80445727a8

esp. the trailing "=" in your token looks suspicious.